# Exponential distribution help

Tags: probability, statistics, exponential-function

Terry has a part-time job at a call centre. Calls to the call centre occur according to a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$ calls per minute. Terry decide to measure the time that elapses between each call. He observes that the time elapsed before the first call is $T_1$ minutes and the time elapsed between the first and second calls is $T_2$ minutes. $T_1$ and $T_2$ are independent and have the same distribution.

**Question:**

State the distribution of $T_1$ and $T_2$, with parameters

**My answer:**

$T_1$,$T_2$ ~ Exponential($\lambda$/$60$)

Am I reading the question correctly? Do you think my ($\lambda$/$60$) is correct?

Comment: The times (in minutes) have exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$. You  have chosen to measure time in seconds, but that does not seem to be what is asked for.